# xcode, errors during compilation on iPhone Simulator 64bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I creted application with iOS SDK 6.1. Everything works fine, but today I checked my app on iOS Simulator for iPhone 64bit. The following screen shows errors at compile.

For example,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_CFRelease", referenced from: 
-[Reachability dealloc] in Reachability.o
```

or

```
"_CFRunLoopGetCurrent", referenced from:
  -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
  -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.o
```

This Reachability class I used in another project and works on iPhone Sim 64b. Can anyone help me with this ?

[image]

Comment: All these linker errors look like you haven't included all frameworks in your project. Make sure you included at least Foundation and UIKit.

Comment: I linked frameworks rm SDK 6.1. Is it ok ?

Comment: As you wrote, problem is with linked frameworks. I removed all frameworks but count of errors was the same. After adding all frameworks again, count of errors has not changed. I have avaliable frameforks to SDK 6.1. It is correct for iOS7 64bit ?

Comment: As far as I know these errors are not related to 64bit. Can you build the app for other iOS 7 versions? Perhaps the iOS 7 SDK is not installed (correctly)?

Comment: `I linked frameworks rm SDK 6.1. Is it ok ?` Does that mean that you do not support iOS 7? AFAIK 64bit is only supported with iOS 7.

Comment: Ok solved. Problem was with validator architecture, I removed arm64 and "Build active Architecture Only" to NO and works!. Thx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be in arc and file you have added has nonarc code.
remove dealloc and check you have added all framework added which required for rechability class.

Comment: ok, but other errors are not depended on Reachability class. Maybe U have something wrong in project settings ...?